set selected item in ajax based multi column select2 using jquery
I have a select2 item with below code
$('.drpCustomer').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/Ajax/GetCustomers',
    dataType: 'json',
      processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data.map(function (item) {
          return {
            id: item.customerID, 
            text: item.customerName,
            contactNo: item.contactNo 
          };
        })
      };
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error('AJAX error: ', textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  },
  templateResult: function (data) {
    if (!data.id) {
      return data.text;
    }
    return $('<table class="w-100"><tr>' +
      '<td>' + data.text + '</td>' + 
      '<td>' + (data.contactNo ? data.contactNo :'') + '</td>' +
      '</tr></table>');
  },
  templateSelection: function (data) {
    return $('<table class="w-100"><tr>' +
      '<td>' + data.text + '</td>' + 
      '<td>' + (data.contactNo ? data.contactNo : '') + '</td>' + 
      '</tr></table>');
  }
});

I have a table where I am showing customers on click of customer in that table I have below code to select that customer in select2
$('body').on('click', '.txtCustomerID, .txtCustomerName', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('.txtCustomerID').text();
  var cname = $(this).parents('tr').find('.txtCustomerName').text();
  var cmobile = $(this).parents('tr').find('.txtCustomerMobile').text();
  var option = new Option(cname +" " +cmobile, id, true, true);//******* Notice here
  $('.drpCustomer').html(option).trigger('change');
});

this is selecting it but visually it is not same as I select an item from select2, because in templateSelection it is rendering as table
I tried to pass table as text in new option('<table>...</table>')
but it is showing [object object]
and also tried as below
var option = new Option({ text: cname, contactNo :cmobile}, id, true, true);
with this also it shows [object object]
